# How to get Firebase uid in Dialogflow webhook?

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

Let's say I want to book a hotel room from my iOS app which requires logging in with Firebase.

After the user says "book me a room", I want the bot to retrieve the Firebase `uid` of the user and modify the Firebase database accordignly using his `uid`.

How should I send the id and retrieve it in my webhook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For nodejs...You will need firebase admin sdk for that.. the client side need to post with their firebase tocken id and then the backend gets the token and converts it to uid, and then with their uid and update your database for booking room. For more documentation, link to Firebase admin docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens.  It is better to ensure verifying users first, or simply for testing development users can post you their uid directly.

Comment: I understand, but how should I send the token to the server when a bot request is made?

Comment: What backend are you using for thr bot, eg. Nodejs, iisnode? Please describe more.

Comment: Firebase cloud functions

Comment: There are some steps you need to follow, such as installing firebase on your computer and then write the code for handling the post and then deploy it to the cloud functions. For more info Goto browser and Open firebase website and navigate to cloud functions, which if first time, should show instruction npm install -g firebase-tools, then change directory to your project or create nodejs project new if no project. Then enter firebase init and after writing the nodejs simply firebase deploy. If you need the actual code that should work for you then let know and give you a start

Comment: I already have some functions working. The problem is sending the uid from the client :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused here. But I got a workaround. By sending an event instead of a query, because the event can take parameters. You can put the firebase uid into the parameters. Below is some of my javascript code.

```
function sendEvent(eventName,params){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ event:{
        name: "WELCOME",data:{uid:"somethindrandom"}
    }, lang: "zh-CN", sessionId: sessionId }),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
```

I send an event to trigger the default welcome Intent by eventName "WELCOME", carrying a uid parameter. Then you can get the uid parameter from `#Welcome.uid`, and transmit to you webhook.
[image: Firebase console screenshot]]